# "Read this post in our app" opening iTunes Store even though I have Stack Exchange installed

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, ios-app

Whenever I select "Read this post in our App" on the Stack Overflow mobile site, I get sent to the iTunes Store even though I have Stack Exchange installed.

First, for a split second, a confirmation box pops up whether I want to "open this page in Stack Exchange". Quickly after that, the app gets switched to the iTunes Store automatically.

I instead expect the app not to switch to the iTunes Store.

---

I am using Safari (no content blockers, cache and cookies cleared) on iOS 9.2.1 (not jailbroken and never was before) on an iPhone 6. One more possibly relevant detail is that my phone is set to German and I am using the German App Store.

> Here is a GIF demonstrating the problem:
>   [image: GIF]
>   (Click the GIF to view in better quality)

Comment: I may want to migrate your question to here: http://stackapps.com/

Comment: Just tried what you mentioned on an iPhone 6S with iOS 9.2.1. It should be noted that it does NOT open the 'App Store' app, but the 'iTunes Store' app. The first time when I tried this with Chrome, it opened the iTunes Store app and all the other times it correctly opened the Stack Exchange app. Safari behaves different and buggy.

Comment: @DanielCheung: Why's that?

Comment: @DanielCheung To http://meta.stackexchange.com/ you mean.

Comment: @Alex I can validate this. I just saw that it showed me the App in a App Store-like layout, I didn't know the iTunes Store could show apps.

Comment: @RAnders00 It tricked me as well for the first few seconds. I just thought it would be good to mention it in order to help with debugging.

Comment: How about using Smart App Banners? Seems like officially only for Safari, but should be some 3rd party solutions for other browsers as well. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Comment: @DanielCheung Why? This question doesn't belong on stackapps.

Comment: @cybermonkey Really, hoho~ I must have got it wrong then.

Comment: "(Click the GIF to view in better quality)". Stackoverflow should be opening gifs in better quality than the original link

Comment: @Holmes It's because SE only supports the `.gif` format and modern services like imgur itself or gfycat offer better quality via HTML5 video.

Comment: @Alex re Smart App Banners vs what we have now, we explicitly decided against using Smart App Banners since it's only supported in Safari and we didn't really get a say over when they show up or not. I put more details in my announcement about this feature: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231190/launch-ios-app-from-sites

Comment: @RAnders00 you posted this in the right place, really any Meta site works fine (they all show up in my search). I've been trying to find quick fixes for this for a few weeks now, I'm looking into doing a real fix. It's to do with the new "[] wants to open []" pop-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed as of 2/26/16, we now properly link to the application and not the iTunes Store on devices running iOS 9+.